# Using R to append a row to a .csv file

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, append

I have a .csv file with 175 rows and 6 columns. I want to append a 176th row. My code is as follows:

```
x <- data.frame('1', 'ab', 'username', '<some.sentence>', '2017-05-04T00:51:35Z', '24')

write.table(x, file = "Tweets.csv", append = T)
```

What I expect to see is:

[image]

Instead, my result is:

[image]

How should I change my code?

Comment: add `quote=F` in your `write.table(..)`

Comment: also add sep = ","

Answer (score 11):

```
write.table(x, file = "Tweets.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE,
  col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: how can I append rows to the head of the csv file instead of attaching at the bottom?